# VB - Issue using XPath reading an XML

Tags: vb.net, xpath

I am currently trying to read in an XML node from a filepath which I pass to my method.

```
Public Function ReadXMLForIsite(xmlFileName As String)
    Dim IsitePath As String
    Dim doc As New XPathDocument(xmlFileName)
    Dim nav As XPathNavigator
    Dim iter As XPathNodeIterator

    nav = doc.CreateNavigator
    iter = nav.Select("GovTalkMessage/Header") 'Node name
    'Loop through the records in that node
    While iter.MoveNext
        Dim lstNav As XPathNavigator
        'Get the data we need from the node
        Dim iterNews As XPathNodeIterator
        lstNav = iter.Current
        iterNews = lstNav.SelectDescendants(XPathNodeType.Element, False)
        'Loop through the child nodes
        While iterNews.MoveNext
            Debug.WriteLine(iterNews.Current.Name & ": " & iterNews.Current.Value)
        End While
    End While

    Return IsitePath
End Function
```

Every time i run this method (even with different node names) the variable 'iter' states that 'debugger display proxy is a type and cannot be used as an expression'. This occurs just before the while statement, therefore does not go in. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Jacob and Luke...hmmm!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to load your `Xml` into an `XDocument`.

```
Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("X:\Jacob.Freeman\RTI\TestXML\0001R.xml")
Dim headerNode = xdoc.Descendants.First(Function(x) x.Name.LocalName = "Header")
For Each desc In headerNode.Descendants()
  Console.WriteLine(desc.Name.LocalName + ":" + desc.Value)
Next
Console.ReadLine()
```